# React Not Attaching DOM to the HTML

Tags: reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am having some problem in my ReactJs code. Everything is compiling without any error using webpack. But after webpack dev server started and when I am browsing to localhost:9000 nothing is inserted into the DOM from ReactJs.

I am running **`npm start`** on terminal.

> Here is all the code that i have written -

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
}
```

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true,
    "modules": true
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "rules": {
    "quotes": [2, "single"],
    "strict": [2, "never"],
    "react/jsx-uses-react": 2,
    "react/jsx-uses-vars": 2,
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 2
  },
  "plugins": [
    "react"
  ]
}
```

**.jslintrc**

```
{
  "node": true,
  "browser": true,
  "esnext": true,
  "newcap": false
}
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Forms in React Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root' class="container">
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="/static/bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

    class IndexComponent extends React.Component{
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <input type="text" value="Shawn" />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    ReactDOM.render(<IndexComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));

**package.json**
{
  "name": "chapter4",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "ReactJS forms example",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "lint": "eslint src"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "eslint": "^3.19.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.3",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "webpack": "^2.4.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4"
  }
}
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src')],
      },
      {
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'react-hot-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              // cacheDirectory: 'babel_cache',
              presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

  }
};
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JS console? Or do you not have any errors either during compilation as well as runtime errors?

Comment: Open your console and check if there are any errors. That would point you in the right direction.

Comment: @saadq No errors on the console.

Comment: @AndrewLi Already posted the code and given the link of the gist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution. 
In the **`rules`** part I am doing some mistake. Following will be the correct rules.

```
rules: [{
  test: /\.jsx?$/,
  include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/')],
  use: [
    {
      loader: 'react-hot-loader'
    },
    {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
    }
  ]
}]
```

This will be the correct webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/')
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/')],
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'react-hot-loader'
        },
        {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
      ]
    }]
  }
};
```

Thanks to all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

In your webpack.confg.js you have the following:

```
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index' // <-- no src dir in project
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    // new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src')], // <-- no src dir in project
      },
      {
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'react-hot-loader'
          },
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              // cacheDirectory: 'babel_cache',
              presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]

  }
};
```

You don't have a src directory in this project.

Fix: Make a src directory and move your index.js file in it. You also have a problem with the way you're trying to bring in react-hot-loader and not excluding node_modules. Try this for your module section:

```
module: {
    loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loaders: ['react-hot-loader', 'babel-loader?presets[]=es2015&presets[]=react&presets[]=stage-2&presets[]=stage-0'],
            include: [path.join(__dirname, 'src')],
            exclude: '/node_modules/'
        }
    ]
}
```

Tested and it works on my local.